# How to resolve a nested item in a graphql query

Tags: react-apollo, graphql-js, prisma

I'm attempting the following:

```
const CURRENT_USER_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    me {
      id
      email
      name
      permissions
      cart {
        id
        quantity
        item {
          id
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

but I'm unable to properly resolve the item field.

Here's the cart resolver (it properly resolves, but only for fields with scalar return values:

```
async function cart(parent, args, ctx, info) {

  const cart = await ctx.prisma.user({ id: parent.id }).cart()

  return cart
}

module.exports = {
  cart,
}
```

It only resolves the scalar values, `id` and `quantity`. The `item` field is a CartItem type:

```
type CartItem {
  id: ID!
  quantity: Int!
  item: Item!
  user: User!
}
```

How can I write the resolver so that I won't get this error, for instance:

`Message: Cannot return null for non-nullable field CartItem.item., Location: [object Object], Path: me,cart,2,item`

The prisma database has the proper relationships to both item and user--I can see them in the prisma database. I just can't properly resolve the item. If I return with a valid item id, I'll get that item.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, when you run `await ctx.prisma.user({ id: parent.id }).cart()`, prisma will only get you scalar values and these are the only ones being forwarded out of your `cart` resolver

You need to create a resolver for that specific field. Something like this:

```
const Cart = {
  item: (parent, args, ctx, info) => {
    return ctx.prisma.cart({ id: parent.id }).item()  
  },
}

export { Cart as default }
```

Then you'll need to include the resolver file when you define the schema for your server:

```
import Cart from './resolvers/Cart';

const schema = {
  typeDefs: 'api/schema.graphql',
  resolvers: {
    Query,
    Mutation,
    Cart,    
  },
  context: async (request) => {
    // whatever you had here before
  },
};
const server = new GraphQLServer(schema);
```

This approach also allows you to expose computed fields for your types (e.g.: An field where you calculate the average of all the cart items).

P.S.: I'd change your schema a little bit. I'd create a `CartItem` with references to `quantity: Int` and `item: Item`, and include these inside your `Cart`